# What am I missing because I keep getting a, "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to do a for loop by item within python3. What could I possibly be missing?

```py
def add_rows(sq_list):
    rowNum = [[0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0]]
    
    for row in rowNum:
        total = 0
        for column in sq_list[row]:
            total += column
            
        print("Row total is:", total)
    
add_rows([[1, 3, 8],
          [2, 4, 6],
          [7, 9, 0]])
```

Comment: First of all you should enter your piece of code here, not an image.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: What's your expected output? What's the error? why are you using picture instead of typing it here?

Answer (score -1):

When you iterate over rows, row is whole list. So your second iteration should be over single elements. So it should look like this (for instance):

```
for row in rowNum:
    total = 0
    for element in row:
        total += element
    
    print(...)
```

Comment: please don't answer poorly asked questions such as this one.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is why I got downvoted ;'( But I tried to correct his question,because he is new.